# Stupid thing on checks and sums - Python

Tags: python, if-statement, sum

Which is more CPU intensive, to do an if(x==num): check, or to do a sum x+y?

Comment: On modern CPUs we are talking about nanoseconds of difference.

Comment: Python is definitely the wrong language to count CPU cycles. And even in C, this would be a laughable nano-optimization. That's not even mentioning that it depends so heavily on compiler, compiler flags, and CPU that it's not funny anymore.

Comment: it was more a curiosity then alnithing else

Comment: why don't you do the test yourself, looks simple enough ... either way I believe the difference will be irrelevant ... simple statements/operations cant kill your cpu ...

Comment: Since an equality check is implemented on x86 using a subtraction followed by a branch vs. a single addition the result should be quite obvious (but then python has to add so much extra code to those instruction that one wouldn't notice the difference anyhow and who knows what code it would really generate?). Though even in C, assuming a worst case scenario (the if is highly unpredictable) I wouldn't worry about the handful cycles.

Comment: This question doesn't fit SO format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat incomplete because you are comparing two different operations. If you need to add two things together then testing `x==y` isn't going to get you anywhere. So presumably you want to compare

```
if y != 0:
    sum += y
```

with

```
sum +=y
```

It's a lot more complex for interpreted languages like Python, but on the hardware a test for non-zero introduces a branch and that in itself can be expensive. But I wouldn't want to say which would be faster without timing.

Throw into the equation different performance characteristics of different architectures and you have another confounding factor.

As always, you are best to write your code in the most natural maintainable way first and then time it. If you feel you need to extract more performance use a profiler to find hot spots and then optimise.